# JOptionPane YES_NO_OPTION not understood exception

Tags: java, exception, joptionpane

So I have the code

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javafx.application.Application;


public abstract class HHGUI extends Application {
    JOptionPane yesno = new JOptionPane();
    public HHGUI() {
        int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you want the ground to generate from premade file?","Read Ground From File", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            Manager.plateaucreator();
            System.exit(0);
        }
         else {
             Manager.randplateaucreator();
             System.exit(0);
         }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and I keep getting the error

```
Exception in Application constructor
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:873)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class HHGUI
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$7(LauncherImpl.java:819)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application HHGUI
```

and I have looked through other questions and cant find anything I am missing to cause this error. I have read up on JOptionPanes but am still unfamiliar with them so help solving this error or help finding what is causing it would be appreciated.

Comment: In a JavaFX application, you should use class [javafx.scene.control.Alert](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) rather than `JOptionPane` and the code to display the `Alert` should be in the [start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#start-javafx.stage.Stage-) method of class `javafx.application.Application`

Comment: I meant the `start()` method in class `HHGUI`.

Comment: You can't invoke an abstract class. Remove the `abstract` modifier and implement `public void start(Stage primaryStage)  {/*to be used instead of the constructor*/}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't invoke an abstract class. Remove the `abstract` modifier and implement `start` method:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;  

public class HHGUI extends Application {

    JOptionPane yesno = new JOptionPane();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)  {
        int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you want the ground to generate from premade file?","Read Ground From File", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("NO");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Although it is possible to use swing `JOptionPane`, in JavaFx `Alert` control  should be used :

```
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HHGUI extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)  {

        Alert yesNo = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION,
                "Do you want the ground to generate from premade file?",
                ButtonType.YES,
                ButtonType.NO);
        yesNo.setTitle("Read Ground From File");
        Optional<ButtonType> result = yesNo.showAndWait();

        if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }else{
            System.out.println("No");
        }
    }
}
```